# Drupal and Multisite

Tags: drupal

I have set out a drupal multisite but need help to share stats between the network of sites like here on stackoverflow.

I need to show how many a user has posted on a node on the main site.

Comment: You should checkout RDF related modules I hope..

Comment: you can define multiple databases in each Drupal installation and switch them on the fly